# cuál es el error que no me permite imprimir las respuestas de las preguntas 7 y 8 con lista desplegable?

Tags: javascript, html5, lista

Al parecer estoy utilizando mal el código para listas desplegables, soy apenas un estudiante de preparatoria y no encuentro la forma correcta de hacerlo. Ya investigué pero no importa cuantas veces corrija, siempre están mal esas dos preguntas y nunca se imprimen. Por lo que sé el error se encuentra dentro del js en la función Calificar. Solo escribí el código de las dos preguntas que me ocasionan el problema. También me serviría de ayuda si me diesen un consejo de como imprimir las respuestas en la parte superior de donde se encuentran las preguntas. El proyecto se trata de un examen con js que califique como "correcto" o "incorrecto" utilizando radio button, checkbox y listas desplegables. Me tomé la libertad de hacerlo sobre el videojuego UNDERTALE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Undertale Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="formatoexamen.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-titulo">
        <p class="titulo">
            ¿QUE TANTO SABES ACERCA DE UNDERTALE?  </p>
    </div>
    <div id="container">

            <label for="nombre">Introduzca su nombre:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"><br><br>

        <header>
            <p class="responde">Responde las siguientes preguntas</p>
        </header>
        <br>
        <div id="resultado"></div>
        

        <h3>7. ¿Qué ocurre si, en cierto momento del juego, vendes tu alma?</h3>

        <select name="p7">
                <option value=1>Cambia el final de la ruta neutral.</option>
                <option value=2>Nada. Es algo que se dice, pero no tiene cambios en el juego</option>
                <option value=3>Cambia el final de la ruta pacifista.</option><!----> 
                <option value=4>En el juego, dejan de reconocerte como humano.</option>
        </select><br>
        <br>

        <h3>8. ¿Qué son las Amalgamas?</h3>
        <select name="p8">
            <option value=1>Clones fallidos del niño caido.</option>
            <option value=2>Intentos fallidos de resucitar al hijo del rey.</option>
            <option value=3>Monstruos inyectados con LOVE.</option>
            <option value=4>Monstruos con DETERMINACIÓN.</option><!----> 
        </select><br><br>

        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="Calificar()">
       
        <br><br><br>
        <footer>
            <p>Tus calificación aparecerá  en la parte de arriba </p>
            
            <p id="mensaje7"></p>
            <p id="mensaje8"></p>

        </footer>
    </div>
    

<script>
           
           function Calificar(){
            var aciertos=0;

             var preg7=document.getElementById('p7').value;
            if (preg7==3){
                document.getElementById('mensaje7').innerHTML =
                        "7.- Correcto";
                aciertos=aciertos+1;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('mensaje7').innerHTML =
                        "7.- Incorrecto";
                
            } 
            
            var preg8=document.getElementById('p8').value;
            if (preg8==4){
                document.getElementById('mensaje8').innerHTML =
                        "8.- Correcto";
                aciertos=aciertos+1;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('mensaje8').innerHTML =
                        "8.- Incorrecto";
                
            }  
            
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saludos. En cada elemento declara con el mismo del `name` la propiedad `id`; estas usando `getElementById` pero a cada elemento solo le pusiste `name`; estos son distintos.

Answer (score 0):

Como te comentaron asignarle un id a cada elemento que vayas a utilizar facilita el acceder a este elemento y poder utilizarlo según desees.

> También me serviría de ayuda si me diesen un consejo de como imprimir
> las respuestas en la parte superior de donde se encuentran las
> preguntas.

En cuanto a lo anterior no estoy muy seguro de que es lo que deseas, pero incorpore una forma dinámica de agregar el texto de las respuestas en la parte superior de la página.

Las dos líneas siguientes te permitirán obtener el texto del option seleccionado en el select.

```
    var sel7 = document.getElementById("p7");
    var text7= sel7.options[sel7.selectedIndex].text;
```

Luego al final de la función calificar agrego el texto obtenido de los select/option, en la primera de estas líneas inicializo con un string vacío "" para no acumular texto si es que el botón enviar se presiona múltiples veces y además concatenamos `"<br>"` para realizar saltos de línea.

```
    document.getElementById('respuestas').innerHTML = "";
    
    document.getElementById('respuestas').innerHTML += " RESPUESTAS"  + "<br>";
    document.getElementById('respuestas').innerHTML += " ----------"  + "<br>";
    document.getElementById('respuestas').innerHTML += "7.- " + text7  + "<br>";
    document.getElementById('respuestas').innerHTML += "8.- " + text8  + "<br>";
```

el texto finalmente se ubicará dentro del div que está en la parte superior de la página

```
<div id="respuestas">

</div>
```

```js
var respuestas = document.getElementById('respuestas');


function Calificar(){
            var aciertos=0;

            var sel7 = document.getElementById("p7");
            var text7= sel7.options[sel7.selectedIndex].text;

            var sel8 = document.getElementById("p8");
            var text8= sel8.options[sel8.selectedIndex].text;

            var preg7=document.getElementById('p7').value;
            if (preg7==3){
                document.getElementById('mensaje7').innerHTML =
                        "7.- Correcto";      
                aciertos=aciertos+1;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('mensaje7').innerHTML =
                        "7.- Incorrecto";               
            } 
  
            
            var preg8=document.getElementById('p8').value;
            if (preg8==4){
                document.getElementById('mensaje8').innerHTML =
                        "8.- Correcto";
                aciertos=aciertos+1;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById('mensaje8').innerHTML =
                        "8.- Incorrecto";
                
            } 
            
            document.getElementById('respuestas').innerHTML = "";
            
            document.getElementById('respuestas').innerHTML += " RESPUESTAS"  + "<br>";
            document.getElementById('respuestas').innerHTML += " ----------"  + "<br>";
            document.getElementById('respuestas').innerHTML += "7.- " + text7  + "<br>";
            document.getElementById('respuestas').innerHTML += "8.- " + text8  + "<br>";
            
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Undertale Test</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="respuestas">

    </div>

    <div class="container-titulo">
        <p class="titulo">
            ¿QUE TANTO SABES ACERCA DE UNDERTALE? </p>
    </div>
    <div id="container">

        <label for="nombre">Introduzca su nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"><br><br>

        <header>
            <p class="responde">Responde las siguientes preguntas</p>
        </header>
        <br>
        <div id="resultado"></div>


        <h3>7. ¿Qué ocurre si, en cierto momento del juego, vendes tu alma?</h3>

        <select name="p7" id="p7" onChange="p7Function(this);">
            <option value=1>Cambia el final de la ruta neutral.</option>
            <option value=2>Nada. Es algo que se dice, pero no tiene cambios en el juego</option>
            <option value=3>Cambia el final de la ruta pacifista.</option><!---->
            <option value=4>En el juego, dejan de reconocerte como humano.</option>
        </select><br>
        <br>

        <h3>8. ¿Qué son las Amalgamas?</h3>
        <select name="p8" id="p8" onChange="p8Function(this);">
            <option value=1>Clones fallidos del niño caido.</option>
            <option value=2>Intentos fallidos de resucitar al hijo del rey.</option>
            <option value=3>Monstruos inyectados con LOVE.</option>
            <option value=4>Monstruos con DETERMINACIÓN.</option><!---->
        </select><br><br>

        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="Calificar()">

        <br><br><br>
        <footer>
            <p>Tus calificación aparecerá en la parte de arriba </p>

            <p id="mensaje7"></p>
            <p id="mensaje8"></p>

        </footer>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```